# Determine the Winding Numbers of the Chinese Unicom Symbol

Tags: complex-analysis, plane-curves, winding-number

I'm practicing with [Winding Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number), and encountered an interesting example. You might be familiar with this liantong symbol, the logo of China Unicom:

[image: China Unicom]

Suppose we make this into a fully closed and connected curve, and try to determine the Winding Numbers of the various points in the symbol. For instance:

*Find the winding numbers of the closed curve shown below at $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5$*

[image: Winding Numbers of Liantong]

---

It seems to me that for each $z$, the winding number $W(z)$ is:

1. $W(z_1)=0$ (since it is outside the curve)
2. $W(z_2)=1$ (since it falls to the left of the curve in one loop)
3. $W(z_3)=-2$ (since it falls to the right of the curve in two loops)
4. $W(z_4)=0$ (since it falls to the right and to the left of the curve twice each, cancelling out)
5. $W(z_5)=-1$ (since it falls to the right of the curve in one loop)

Would you agree with these winding numbers (and given reasoning)? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Crossing the curve (at a point where the curve doesn't intersect itself) changes the winding number by $\pm 1$.
So the winding numbers of $z_1$ and $z_3$ must differ by $1$, not $4$.

Comment: Okay, I agree with you that $W(z_3) \ne -4$. But when I trace the curve around $z_3$ I keep getting $W(z_3)=-2$ now. This one is tricky.

Comment: $W(z_3)$ is definitely $-1$. But if you want to discuss it, you're going to have to label your intersection points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a curve crosses your path from left to right, the winding number increases.

If a curve crosses your path from right to left, the winding number decreases.

[image]

Going from $z_1$ to $z_2$, the curve crosses our path from left to right. Therefore, $\mathrm{W}(z_2)=1$.

Going from $z_1$ to $z_3$, the curve crosses our path from right to left. Therefore, $\mathrm{W}(z_3)=-1$.

Going from $z_3$ to $z_4$, the curve crosses our path from left to right. Therefore, $\mathrm{W}(z_4)=0$.

Going from $z_4$ to $z_5$, the curve crosses our path from right to left. Therefore, $\mathrm{W}(z_5)=-1$.

[image]

Comment: Great explanation! I didn't know it was this easy. I thought I had to trace the curve and keep track of the direction of every boundary around a point to see how the Winding number changes... This is a much simpler approach. Thank you!

Comment: In essence, this method does just that. By noting the direction of the curve at each intersection with a path, we are keeping track of the direction at each boundary along the path.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the curve can be deformed to a union of clockwise and counterclockwise circles, which makes it much easier to find the winding numbers.

[image]